# GWT problem when setting inner html

Tags: gwt, innerhtml

I'm having big trouble while setting text (as HTML) for gwt HTML component. In my case I'm setting my UiBinder template, let's call it foo.ui.xml

```
...
<g:HTMl ui:field="testfield"/>
...
```

Because it's a dialog window I want to dynamically change content of this field. In my View class

```
class MyWidget extends PopupPanel { 

    @UiField
    HTML testfield

   ..

}
```

When showing up popup I'm setting it's content

```
testField.setHTML("<span>Some example <b>of html</b></span>");
```

Resulting in exception

```
Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (Error): Nieznany błąd czasu wykonywania.
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:237)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:132)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:289)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
    at com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element$.setInnerHTML$(Element.java)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DirectionalTextHelper.setInnerTextOrHtml(DirectionalTextHelper.java:240)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DirectionalTextHelper.setTextOrHtml(DirectionalTextHelper.java:184)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML.setHTML(HTML.java:183)
    at foo.app.client.popup.MyWidgetUI.setMessage(MyWidgetUI.java:133)
```

'Nieznany błąd czasu wykonywania.' - means something like 'Unknown error during execution time'.

This bug seems to occur only on IE6,7 browsers. Any ideas about a cause or solution ?

Comment: That's not really valid html, is it? Does it work without the `<b>` tag?

Comment: It's just a sample - It doesn't work without anyway. I just wanted to emphasize use of html tags - point is </b> is missing :-)